# Submitting iOS binary after rejection

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I recently submitted my app and it was rejected due to a bug. I've fixed the issue but I've also implemented new stuff while the app was in review. Now can I upload a binary with these new features or should I submit a bug-free version of the old one?

Answer (score 6):

The review will (as far as is known) be essentially restarted. As such, there's no reason not to submit the most up-to-date version of your app.

Comment: Ok. That's all I wanted to know. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple tested your application and rejected it , because it having some bug. Apple just testing your application, they will not stop to update your application. 
So you can update your application.

But make sure that after implementing new feature, app should not surround by new bug, because apple again test your app step by step, and they will reject it if they find new bug.